# How to use react-hotkeys-hook to submit a form with react-hook-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I want to submit a form with react-hook-form using the useHotKeys from react-hotkeys-hook

I have attached a code sandbox trying this. I want to submit a form when a hotkey is clicked as well as when the submit button is clicked. Can this be done?

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hoot-form-usehotkeys-009rk?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using the handleSubmit method for react-hook-forms. The mistake that is made is that handleSubmit is a callback, hence it needs to be called like this.

```
handleSubmit(onSubmit)()
```

and not like this `handleSubmit(onSubmit)`

Comment: Thanks. But can I use react hook form validation this way?

Comment: Yes, I think that is precisely why I required it. Do not exactly remember the use case as its been a while. But if you can provide a specific use case where you are having any issues, I can help you out.

Comment: Validation doesn’t work this way :( I described my case in question description: new API wasn’t ready.

Sorry, I confused the question with mine about POST submit:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68339351/how-to-make-form-with-post-method-by-using-react-hook-form

Answer (score 0):

My form uses `material-ui-confirm` to conditionally confirm submissions, but when I added the option to submit it by using hotkeys, using `handleSubmit(onSubmit)()`, that confirmation would be ignored.

I did this workaround and it seems to be working, though:

```
  // had to extract confirmation logic to a function
  const confirmSub = async (data: any) => {
    if (!conditions) {
      await confirm({
        title: "Message",
        description: "Desc",
      });
    }
  };

  // fire submission when the user presses ctrl+enter on a textarea
  // notice how onSubmit() is called
  useHotkeys(
    "ctrl+enter",
    () => {
      handleSubmit(async (data) => {
        await confirmSub(data);
        await onSubmit(data);
      })();
    },
    {
      enableOnTags: ["TEXTAREA"],
    },
  );


  const onSubmit = async (data: any) => {
    // have to keep this in case the user uses a button to submit
    await confirmSub(data);
    await mutation.mutate(data);
  };

  // define mutations and rest of the code below
```

Maybe the same logic can be applied to validation, since this way you have access to the `data` object before `handleSubmit` is fired?

A but convoluted, but that's all I got for now.